# image size for iPad

Tags: image, ipad, adobe-indesign, image-size

I'm creating a magazine to read on an iPad and am having problems with creating readable pages. What size (DPI and MB) should my files be? And I'm doing an export from InDesign, are there any suggested steps that should be taken here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPad display is at 132 PPI.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad display is 1024 x 768 - I'd recommend making your images that size.

Comment: Note that the user can switch between portrait and landscape orientations, so you should either provide two versions of each image or ensure that it looks good in either orientation.  Also note that the status bar, if showing, is 20 pixels high, so subtract that from the height if you want an image that fits perfectly on the page if the app shows the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, the image size for iPad is by default 1024x768, but I recommend you to create your file in 1152x1536 px if you want to zoom-in in your image on iPad end keep a good quality of display.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a pdf of the entire document or saving the pages as images? You may also want to consider the way users will be accessing the document (online, each page downloaded or as an application) If it is an application you will be able to have larger page sizes. If online, then download size will definitely become a factor in how it looks. If you shrink the quality too much, your rendered text will be the first thing on the page to suffer.

Have you done any research into what you find a comfortable to read text size (i.e., with popular science, wired, or project magazines? Another one to check is digital2.0 or the first of the RAW applications which was put out) These magazine apps use scrolling text regions in a lot of cases, but you can at least see how they use fonts and how comfortable they will be at different sizes.